# Alternative to Ajax Call

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I am making ajax call to execute python script. I am using flask framework to do so. It goes to URL, execute the script and returns the response. But, python script may take about 10 seconds to execute and return the response. Till then, if user closes or reloads the tab, ajax call and script execution gets interrupted. Of course, I don't want that. So, I am searching for alternative to it or any suggestion so that until server is running, python script execution should be completed, even if tab is closed or reloaded.

Flask file :

```py
@app.route('/<contest_id>/<task_id>/submit')
def submit(contest_id, task_id):
    response = os.popen("python3 static/submit.py "+contest_id+" "+task_id).read()
    return response
```

Ajax Call :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/"+contest_id+"/"+task_id+"/submit",
    success: function(response) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Be aware that your code is very vulnerable to command injection attacks; if someone calls `http:/example.com/;rm%20-rf%20;/`, you'd be in a lot of trouble. Never trustingly put user input (including URL parameters) into shell commands (unless it will be run in a sandbox you control and no-one else can access, but I wouldn't even then)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [beacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API). It guarantees it will not be terminated by the page's closing (though it will if you shut down the browser itself). However, on the flip side, you will not receive a response to your script; it is usually reserved for write-only requests where confirmation or further data is not necessary on the clientside.

```
navigator.sendBeacon(url, data);
```

However, there's still several browsers that [do not support it](https://caniuse.com/#search=beacon).

If you need a response, there's no alternative to AJAX (or page transition).

---

However, your `submit` job should not be terminated if the request it. Of course, you will not get a response if a user browses off of your page, but flask should complete the work. Try this:

```
import time
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    with open('woo1', 'w') as w: pass
    time.sleep(60)
    with open('woo2', 'w') as w: pass
    return "Hello World!"
```

Navigate to http://localhost:5000 and then before the minute is up navigate away; after one minute, you should find both `woo1` and `woo2` in your directory.

Comment: Oh, I will definitely check it. But, response returned is quite important and it is going to be shown as notification. So, I was thinking, can we store it somewhere so that I can display it as notification on some other page on same server ?

Comment: You can't display or store something you never receive; and the only way you'll receive it is if you're using AJAX and you're still on the same page (or if you make a page transition, not cancel it, and the new page has that data). Unless, as @maanijou suggests, you do your processing in a separate thread or process on the server, and fetch the results in a different request.

Comment: Ok, that will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

A common solution for such problems is to use `Celery`. With celery, you can run asynchronous tasks without waiting for the results. It's basically a queue used for running tasks in the background. You can start the task and wait for it to be completed. The task continues to run even if the browser is closed. With right configurations, you can save the results in the database to be checked later.

There is some nice tutorials out there for using celery ([Using celery with flask](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask)). Celery is often used with Redis and Rabbitmq